# Key listener not detecting key presses?

Tags: java, actionlistener, keypress, keylistener, keyevent

I am trying to make my picture move based on the arrow keys being pressed but the key listener is not detecting any key presses. I attached the code for the panel which i add to a frame in a driver.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class RacePanel extends JPanel
{
//variables
private ImageIcon backGround = new ImageIcon("images/back.png");
private Penguin p;
private ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("images/PenguinR.png");
private ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("images/PenguinL.png");
private int x = 10;
//move left and right methods
public void moveLeft(Penguin x)
{
   x.setImageIcon(icon2);
  x.setX(x.getX() - 5);

}
public void moveRight(Penguin x)
{
  x.setImageIcon(icon1);
  x.setX(x.getX() + 5);

}




public RacePanel()
{  
  JPanel RacePanel = new JPanel();  
  super.addKeyListener(new Key());
  setFocusable(true);
  p = new Penguin();
  Timer t = new Timer(50, new Listener());
  t.start();

}

 private class Key implements KeyListener
 {
  public Key()
  { 
     addKeyListener(this);
  }

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
  {
  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
  {

     if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
     {
        moveRight(p);
     }
     if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
     {
        moveLeft(p);
     }   
     if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
     {
        System.out.println("i am listening");
     }
     repaint();         
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
   {   


   }
   }


   //graphics
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
  g.drawImage(backGround.getImage(),0,0,800,600,null);
  g.drawImage(p.getImageIcon().getImage(),p.getX(),p.getY(),50,100,null);
  }
  //action listener .05 second loop
   private class Listener implements ActionListener
  {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {

     repaint();  
  }
  }



  }
```

I know that it is not recognizing key pressed because i added a line of code to print "i am listening" if the up arrow is pressed and nothing prints.
I also know the issue is not because of the timer cause i tested it by adding the moveRight method to the actionPerformed method.

Comment: As per all the other simular questions on the subject, don't use `KeyListener`, it's just annoying, instead use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).  You're example code is adding the `KeyListener` twice, which will result in you potentially getting notified twice

Comment: Also, you will probably want to take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to figure out why your painting process is leaving artefacts each time the component is repainted